# Unable to access Toad model report from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, toad

I would like to send the TOAD model report link to my team members. Toad model report consists of number of HTML and image files. So, I would like to know how should I send the report link? I am getting 404 error every time I am trying to open the HTML report.